# Imprimir valores de um array

Tags: javascript

Quero imprimir os valor de um array que são inseridos com o push sempre que clico num objecto. A função funciona porque os alert aparecem. O problema é que não imprime os valores no paragrafo html.

```
    var x1;
    var y;
    shape.onclick = function(){
        var name=this.id;
        alert(name);
        x1=this.getAttributeNS(null, "cx");
        y=this.getAttributeNS(null, "cy");
        alert(y);

        namecirc=push(name);
        positionX=push(x1);
        positionY=push(y);

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="x="+positionX;


    };
```

html:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Onde estão defenidos esses "arrays"? Por exemplo: `positionX` já é um array? se fôr deve usar não igualdade mas sim `positionX.push(x1);` Tem mais código que falta aqui?

Comment: Sim é um array defini em cima do codigo, var positionX = new Array();

Comment: E o que quer mostrar no `demo`? a array com as posiçöes todas ou só a ultima?

Comment: as posições todas, alterei para positionX.push(x1), mesmo assim não mostra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `.push()` é um método nativo de Array, deve usar assim:

> array.push(novoConteudo);

Assim mude no código para:

```
namecirc.push(name);
positionX.push(x1);
positionY.push(y);
```

Para mostrar uma array no HTML tem várias opções.

Ou usa `JSON.stringify(array)`

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "x=" + JSON.stringify(positionX);
```

Ou usa `array.join('separador')`:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "x=" + positionX.join(', ');
```

Comment: Não consigo mostrar, tenho aqui o codigo completo http://jsfiddle.net/zp0vcc7c/

Comment: @akm Remova `//` daqui: `//var namecirc =new Array();`, assim vai dar: http://jsfiddle.net/cpyq7a8v/

Comment: Obrigado, ja funciona

Comment: @akm se a resposta foi util pode também votar nela, assim contribui em "pontos virtuais" para quem ajudou a resolver o problema :)